# Mssql Select and update together , it updates 2 rows

Tags: sql-server, select

Got a procedure and first I wanna show the Minimun Que number on screen (C#) its working and it shows 501  as minimum que number then update as I write in sp down below , but its updates id 501 and 502 at the same time...
( select id value and update one of the fields that id row has)

any better way to do that ?

```
Create procedure [dbo].[nmr_sp_srd]
(
 @opid int
)
AS
Begin

Begin Transaction

select  Min(Que) from nmr_tbl_srbklynlr where turId=@opid and actpf=1

UPDATE nmr_tbl_srbklynlr
SET actpf= 0
Where Que=(select  Min(Que) from nmr_tbl_srbklynlr where turId=@opid and actpf=1)
Commit Transaction

End
```

Comment: Do both of the records have the same `Que` value?

Comment: No Que numbers are unique  and  created only one time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the double query by storing the value in a variable.  If you want to update at most one row out of all rows matching the `where` clause, you can use `update top (1)`.

```
declare @min_que int

select  @min_que = Min(Que) 
from    nmr_tbl_srbklynlr 
where   turId = @opid and actpf = 1

update  top (1) nmr_tbl_srbklynlr 
set     actpf = 0
where   Que = @min_que

select  @min_que
```